# Generate PDF using iTextsharp

Tags: itext

I have project where I have to generate secure thousands of PDF. I am using itextsharp to generate pdfs. But vendors have to print these PDFs by merging in to one file. Merging of pdf will not available if I secure the PDFs. What should I do? How I secure My PDFs?

Comment: How do you secure them now? What, in contrast, do those vendors allow? In general, though, if you create PDFs which eventually have to be utterly changed by other processes (merging PDFs is quite a radical change!), you hardly can restrict any premission unless you give the rquired passwords (needed to remove those restrictions) to those processes.

Answer (score 0):

When encrypting the documents, you can set a value [ALLOW_ASSEMBLY](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#ALLOW_ASSEMBLY). This means that you allow other parties to assemble/disassemble your documents. Of course, you shouldn't use a user password, only an owner password.